# Is it possible to create a group of Applications on Dock without changing the path?

Tags: applications, macos, dock

Now that I have a bunch of applications on my Dock, I want to create a group to manage similar applications altogether. For example, I want to group a set of graphics apps (e.g. Affinity Designer, Sketch 3, Pixelmator) at one place, and access to them by tapping on the group first, and then selecting the app.

This can be done if you create a new directory and move the apps to it, and then drag and drop the directory to the Dock. However, this changes the path of the app (e.g. `/Applications/Graphics/Pixelmator.app`), which I like to eschew. (That's why I called it *group*, not *directory*.)

Also this has a problem, in that you must drag and drop to the right side of your Dock...

So is it still possible to create a group in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put app aliases to the new folder and then add it do the Dock. You can create an alias by right/secondary clicking on the App and choosing "Create Alias" or pressing <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

[Macworld](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-create-shortcuts-on-mac-3613491/) has an article about aliases and putting them on Dock.

> An even easier way to create an alias and move it to your more convenient location is to hold alt (option) and command while clicking and dragging an item. Drop it onto your desktop (or other convenient location) and you've got yourself an alias in the place you need it to be in one swift step.
>
> You can find the original item for an alias by selecting the alias and choosing File > Show Original.

[image: Make Alias]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I wanted. You can create an alias to the directory that has a set of apps, but you still have to move the apps to the directory, right? This is changing the path of the app, like `/Applications/SomeDirectory/Pixelmator.app`.

Comment: Nope, create an alias to the **app** and then put this alias inside separate directory. This won't change the path to the original app.

Comment: Ah, I see. This still forces me to put a directory to the right side, but for the time being I find this so good. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: BTW which do you recommend more between an alias and a symbolic link in this case?

Comment: Alias for sure. Symbolic links do not "track" the path to the original file. Whenever you can use alias.